# How can I use non-adjacent cells on another sheet for a Data Validation drop-down, and only show non-blank values?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, data-validation

I have a few, non-adjacent cells on one sheet which I want to use as a Source for Data Validation in a cell on another sheet.  However, it seems Data Validation doesn't natively permit this.

So, I tried to do a work-around that involved putting formulas into some adjacent cells on another sheet which would reference the values I wanted from the first sheet.  Then, I named the second range and referenced that name in the Data Validation Source field.

Now I have a problem where, if one of the cells from the first sheet is blank, a cell on the second sheet that references a blank on the first will show `0` instead of being blank.  I tried to work around this by doing something like `=IF(Sheet1!A1="","",Sheet1!A1)`.  However, this doesn't *actually* make the formula result the same as a blank cell.

This all mostly becomes problematic when I want my Data Validation to include an in-cell drop-down.  My choices here appear to be either to have `0` or a blank line in the drop-down wherever there are blanks in the Source data.  If the blanks were true blanks, this wouldn't happen.

So, is there any way to work around this?

---

Example:

Sheet1

A1= `Value1`
A5= `Value2`
A9= `Value3`
A13= `Value4`
A17= (Cell is blank)
A21= (Cell is blank)

Sheet2

A1 `=Sheet1!A1` (returns `Value1`)
A2 `=Sheet1!A5` (returns `Value2`)
A3 `=Sheet1!A9` (returns `Value3`)
A4 `=Sheet1!A13` (returns `Value4`)
A5 `=Sheet1!A17` (returns `0`)
A6 `=IF(Sheet1!A21="","",Sheet1!A21)` (appears blank)

`Sheet2!A1:A6` is named `Validation`.  At `Sheet3!A1`, Data Validation is applied with source `=Validation` and an in-cell drop-down.  The in-cell drop-down shows:

> Value1
>   Value2
>   Value3
>   Value4
>   0

(Blank cell included)

Under these conditions, I'm looking for a configuration that will result in a drop-down in `Sheet3!A1` that only shows `Sheet2!A1:A4` while also keeping `Sheet2!A5:A6` available should they ever be populated.  Alternately, the drop-down in `Sheet3!A1` should show only `Sheet1!A1,Sheet1!A5,Sheet1!A9,Sheet1!A13` while also keeping `Sheet1!A17,Sheet1!A21` available should they ever be populated.

It seems I need a way to either:

- Directly address the non-adjacent cells in `Sheet1`, in my Data Validation Source
  OR
- Get the cells in the `Validation` range in `Sheet2` to *actually* return blank cells when their targets in `Sheet1` are blank.

Comment: This will require at least two methods, pending on how abstract you want to process the information.  When i get to work tomorrow ill give you some starter methods to get you going down the correct road.  In the mean time read up on this posting on StackOverflow: [DataValidation filters Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785186/datavalidation-filters-table)

Comment: @GoldBishop Looking forward to it.  Meanwhile, I've worked around the problem for this particular case.  Still need some help [over here](http://superuser.com/questions/488256/how-do-i-make-a-data-validation-drop-down-exclude-blanks) though.

Answer (score 0):

Using the method described in your original post [How do i make a Data Validation drop-down exclude blanks](https://superuser.com/questions/488256/how-do-i-make-a-data-validation-drop-down-exclude-blanks).

Couple this with these methods:

```
Public Sub ClearDataValidation(destrng As Range)
   destrng.Validation.Delete
End Sub

Public Sub LoadDataValidation(srcrng As Range, destrng As Range)
   'Verify a 1x1 sized Range was passed
   If destrng.Rows.Count <> 1 Or destrng.Columns.Count <> 1 Then
      InvalidValue destrng.Worksheet, "LoadDataValidation", _
            "Range: " & destrng.name & " was passed to method. This method expects a " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            " 1 Row x 1 Column Range to be passed.  Anything outside of the 1x1 " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "size will result in invalid conditions"
      Exit Sub
   End If

   With Range(destrng.Address).Validation
      .Delete
      .Add xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, xlBetween, DistinctValues(srcrng)
   End With
End Sub
```

#### Usage:

```
LoadDataValidation Range("Table1[column1]"), Range("destinationCell")
```