# How do I make a Data Validation drop-down exclude blanks?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, data-validation

Related:  [How can I use non-adjacent cells on another sheet for a Data Validation drop-down, and only show non-blank values?](https://superuser.com/q/488239/50086)

For now, I've worked around the above problem by re-arranging my sheet so all the Data Validation Source cells are in one range.  I'm leaving the above question open though, because I think it still poses an interesting problem.

However, the issue now is that the Data Validation drop-down isn't working in the way I expected it to (and how I believe others are telling me it should).  Even though I've got everything into one named range, Excel still shows blanks in a drop-down that references that range.

Setup:

Sheet 1

A1= (blank) B1= `Header`
A2= `1` B2= `Value1`
A3= `2` B3= `Value2`
A4= `3` B4= `Value3`
A5= `4` B5= (empty)
A6= `5` B6= (empty)
A7= `6` B7= (empty)

`Sheet1!B2:B7` is named `Validation`

`Sheet2!A1` is set to use Data Validation with a Source `=Validation`, and in-cell drop-down.  The drop-down in `Sheet2!A1` shows:

> Value1
>   Value2
>   Value3
>   .
>   .
>   .

(Dots represent blank lines)

How can I get rid of these blank lines in the in-cell drop-down, while still including `Sheet1!B5:B7` in the Data Validation Source?

Note:  I nuked the sheet, and tried it again without column `A` from `Sheet1` (putting values from column `B` in the above example into column `A`), and it worked fine.  Adding Column A back though, brought the blanks back into the Data Validation drop-down.  What do I need to do to keep column `A` as I want it *and* keep the in-cell drop-down clean?

Comment: Okay, I found a solution but really only have about half a clue how it works.  Could someone take a look at this and post an answer that explains it all?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6PcF04bTSOM

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that i use in a current project.

```
'@ws - Worksheet object
'@col - String value
'Notes:
'  - @ws should be the worksheet that contains the Range @col
'  - @col should be a Column/Row based Range, should be only 1 Column or Row
Function UniqueValues(ws As Worksheet, col As String) As Variant

   Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range(col)
   Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

   If Not (rng Is Nothing) Then
      Dim cell As Range, val As String

      For Each cell In rng.Cells
         val = CStr(cell.Value)

         If InStr(1, val, ",") > 0 Then
            val = Replace(val, ",", Chr(130))
         End If

         If Not dict.Exists(val) Then
            dict.Add val, val
         End If

      Next cell
   End If

   'Return value as Variant Array
   UniqueValues = dict.Items
End Function
```

You will probably want to put in a check for a Value `val > 0` ,`val & "" <> ""` or `IsNullOrEmpty(val)`.  `IsNullOrEmpty` is a UDF that i created since VBA does not contain a String method to do this as one.

I have posted several code-snippets at [Microsoft Wikia](http://microsoft.wikia.com/wiki/Excel_2010/Snippets) site.  They are very generic and can be used for just about any purpose, as they are specified.